# getting wrong value in dropdownlist in code behind

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I've read a few different examples of this, and it seems to be a clear newbie question for those that don't fully understand the asp.net page life cycle, sorry still learning.  None of my attempts to fix have panned out.

aspx:

```
...
<%
for( int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
{
  ChildWeightPounds.Items.Add( new ListItem(j.ToString(),j.ToString()));
}
%>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ChildWeightPounds" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListSelected">
     <asp:ListItem Value="">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
...
<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="InsertButton_Click" />
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (Control c in NewPatientForm.Controls)
    {
        ....
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
             TextBox tb = (TextBox)c;
             //Expected response:
             Response.Write( "field: " + tb.ID + " = " + tb.Text + "<br />");
        }
        if (c is DropDownList)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)c;

            //Unexpected response: 
            //this is not giving me my selected value, but only the top item ("--select--")
            Response.Write("field: " + ddl.ID + ", selectedItem: " + ddl.SelectedItem.Value + "<br />");
         }
    }
 }
```

It's pretty clear this is a IsPostBack, DataBind(), problem with my lack of understanding of the page life cycle.  But what doesn't make sense, is i'm iterating through all controls, and textboxes, checkboxes, checkboxlists all work fine, and give me the value in the field, for some reason the dropdownlist doesn't give me the value.

I've tried using the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, I've tried using the DataBind() function, but playing with these, still hasn't gotten me the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue with your example is you are using inline C# within your page with `<% %>`. This isn't advised for `asp.net`. That's more of a legacy/classic ASP approach which won't play well with .NET for many reasons.

Try moving your code that adds the items to the `dropdownlist` from the markup file into the .cs file, and be sure to hook into a page event that happens at or before `OnPreRender`. That is the last point you can alter the page controls and have viewstate/lifecycle work correctly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for( int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    {
        ChildWeightPounds.Items.Add( new ListItem(j.ToString(),j.ToString()));
    }
}
```

It's likely without running your example that the values are being inserted into the `dropdownlist` at the incorrect time in the `lifecycle`, and because of that when you try to access the selected value in the code behind it doesn't work.

Consider the following article on asp.net [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which may assist you.

Comment: Gold! this is it.  Thanks!  Unfortunately putting the for loop in the .cs file doesn't seem very clean.  e.i. I have a bunch of fields (textfields, checkboxes, dropdowsn, etc.)  each is built and displayed on the .aspx file.  Some of the DropDownLists contain nice repeating patterns so it made sense to just add the items inline using <% for()...%>. Building the DropDownLists items in the code behind appears random.  Is there a clean way to do this, that also gives me the values I expect?  Thanks again!

Comment: @russds glad it helped. You're in for an uphill battle if you don't like the concept of code and markup separation in asp.net. It's basically one of the founding principles. If you come from an ASP background I can see how it would seem 'different' but in the end (in my experience with both) there is no question the concept works better with separation. Think of it as one file defines what is on the page, the other defines how it works.

Comment: @russds if you like to define functionality together with your markup you may want to look at ASP.NET MVC (model view controller). May fit better with your style.

Comment: @russds One more comment - you mention you want a clean solution. What I've provided is probably the most common asp.net practice for the task given... you can hook into a control event on the dropdownlist if you'd prefer the data be entered in a directly related event.. either will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust `AutoPostBack="true"` on your DropDownList, and define `OnSelecIndexChanged event`

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ChildWeightPounds" runat="server"
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListSelected" AutoPostBack="true>
         <asp:ListItem Value="">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind

```
void DropDownListSelected(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var value =  ChildWeightPounds.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I prefer not to add AutoPostBack="true" to the drop down, because this refreshes the page (at least from my understanding), and I have a long list of fields, and would require the user to again scroll down and search for the place they were on the form.

Comment: I'am happy to help you russds